# In Kuroko no Basuke, are the characters ever compared to professional players?

Tags: kuroko-no-basket

So, in *Kuroko no Basuke* (or, *The Basketball Which Kuroko Plays*, as suits you), we see that the Generation of Miracles has some pretty wacky basketball superpowers. I'm no basketball expert, but it seems like if you took the five of them and transferred them into the real world (powers and all), they would beat most actual NBA teams. And the thing is, they're just 10th-graders. Sure, maybe they're the best 10th-graders (even the best high-schoolers) in Japan, but surely they can't be as good as *professional* players in the KnB universe, can they?

Which brings me to my question - does the manga ever talk about how good professional basketball players (NBA or otherwise) are as compared to the high-school players the story focuses on?

Comment: I have to disagree that the information is inaccurate. The pages take place in Hyuuga's flashback when he was in middle school. It has to have been at least two years ago then, as the flashback takes place during his middle school days. He is also more focused on Mibuchi as opposed to Midorima, and it does not seem that he has lost his ambition to play, so I think it is safe to assume that it would have taken place in the first two years of middle school, which would have made it at least three years ago from the present time. At that time, I believe Ray Allen was still with the Boston Celtics

Comment: (The above comment by @satoda should be in response to @​krikara's answer below, but somehow ended up here instead.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Kuroko no Basuke (manga) never references any actual NBA pro by explicitly stating a name, but they have shown panels of professional basket ball players insinuating that they are from the NBA. The characters depicted don't actually resemble any specific pro, but rather a generic player - tall, built, and African-American.

It does seem like the Generation of Miracles could beat real life NBA teams, but the manga does indirectly explain how the Generation of Miracles will not prevail.

Take Kise's copying ability for example. He can only copy people's techniques that he is capable of executing, but because NBA players are so much bigger, faster, and better, his copying won't work.

Or in Midorima's case, he might have the insane accuracy as usual, but an NBA player can easily block his shot.

In the end, however, I don't think Kuroko no Basket will ever mention and compare with top NBA pros. There are certain things that are completely impossible, like Kuroko's phantom shot. It doesn't even theoretically work in real life because NBA plays man to man defense, where each member playing has to always follow their assigned opponent. You can't just misdirect someone following you and not see you shooting.

And don't even get me started on eagle vision...

**UPDATE**: In one of the latest chapters (242) that I haven't read yet, [Ray Allen](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ray_Allen) of the Boston Celtics is shown as the first NBA player in Kuroko. This is somewhat inaccurate though, as Ray Allen has been part of the Miami Heat for 2 years now.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Actually, they only did it once. When they compared Ray Allen to the SG of Rakuzan.

Comment: I thought I missed it at first, and was mad at myself because I am from Boston myself. Then I realized it happened in one of the most recent chapters that I didn't read yet.

Answer (score -1):

they do mention shaq during the anime as well as tiger woods saying they influenced rule changes on there professions

Comment: Did they mention how good Shaq was in comparison to the highschool player, though?